# Matrix space, fixed eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

During my basic course of Linear Algebra the problem of characterising matrix spaces was touched upon very lightly and now I have hard time with this problem.
We work with symmetric matrices n $\times$ n. For each matrix we can write down eigenvalue problem. Suppose all eigenvalues are different. How will the space change if one eigenvalue is twice-degenerate?

Comment: "matrix space" ? Do you mean vector space ?

Comment: A vector space constructed from matrices. Symmetric matrices form $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$-dimension linear space over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ah, then are you talking of a subspace formed by the symmetric matrices with double Eigenvalues ?

Comment: Yes. Firstly, I don't quite understand whether this subspace ls linear.

Comment: The subset isn't closed under addition. $\text{diag}(1,1,2)+\text{diag}(1,2,2)=\text{diag}(2,3,4)$, so can't form a vector space.

Comment: Fine. So what can be said about it?

Comment: I finally understood that the big idea behind this question was Von Neumann - Wigner theorem. So it should be answered in a different manner (in terms of independent parameters), it's covered in their pioneer article from 1929)

Answer (score 0):

If an eigenvalue is double, then you need to find two eigenvectors from your generated space. Sometimes, depending on the exercise given, the space you find after solving the equation $ (A - λI)x = 0 $ when $ λ $ is a twice-degenerate eigenvalue, you may get a solution that will be like a general space (example : a plane). The big change when you have twice-degenerate eigenvalues is when using Cayley Hamilton theorem. I can give a specific example about the space of the eigenvalue-vectors when the eigenvalue is double/twice-degenerate if you want to.

Comment: Charalampos Filippatos, I misunderstood me. Space of symmetric matrices is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$-dimension linear space. Here I am asking how it will be changed if I add constraints: 1) all eigenvalues are different 2) there is twice-degenerate eigenvalue. Will it still be a linear space? Of what dimensionality?

Comment: Oh well sorry, now you formed your question correctly